# Python Autograd Confusion, output seems wrong

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I am coding an neural net to learn to solve a differential equation. For this stage I am asking it to solve the very simple equation dy/dx = 3 where 0 <= x <= 1.

This means that the output of the neural net NN(x) should be such that NN'(x) - 3 = 0. What I do is that I have an original grid X that splits up the space into intervals, where x \elementof [0, h, 2h, ...1 - h, 1] where h is the interval size.

```
X = torch.linspace(0,1,N, requires_grad=True)
.
.
.
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    

    input = X
    output = model(input)
    predicted_derivative = autograd.grad(output, input, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(output), create_graph=True)[0]
    loss = criterion(predicted_derivative - 3, torch.zeros(N))
    
    optimiser.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()  
    optimiser.step()

    #print("Iteration: " + str(epoch) + " Loss: " + str(loss))
```

For simple non-neural net functions like sin/cos, etc, the autograd seems to work properly.

But for my neural net, the computed predicted_derivative (NN'(x)) quickly converges to 3 (as it should), however the output NN(x) (called 'output') seems wildly incorrect. The output should be 3*X + C as that is the solution to the differential equation, but it is a mess of numbers that when plotted look like white noise.

I must be misunderstanding how the autograd function works, but in what way?
[image: My console output]